# Cannot deploy InstalledPackage in Package Manifest with any other types!

Tags: ide

I am trying to delete some of the apex classes from my sandbox and deploy the changes to production and keep getting the following error :-

**Cannot deploy InstalledPackage in Package Manifest with any other types!*

Some people they mentioned this is an issue with the new v.28 IDE and works fine with version 27. Is this a valid statement? and how I can find old versions of the IDE?

Comment: I believe it's duplicate with http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/14020/installedpackage-failure-when-deploying-to-sandbox