# how to roll back to force.com ide v27

Tags: force.com, deployment, ide

Ran in to this deployment issue error "Cannot deploy InstalledPackage in Package Manifest with any other types!" the only solutions i can find is to roll back from v28 to v27... but i cant find a copy for mac or pc any suggestions on rolling back?

[InstalledPackage Failure When Deploying to Sandbox](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/14020/installedpackage-failure-when-deploying-to-sandbox)

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

[Read CloudMike's answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/14020/installedpackage-failure-when-deploying-to-sandbox/14161#14161):

As for installing a previous version of the Force.com IDE plug-in you must **FIRST** remove the current version.

1. Go to the Eclipse menu **Help --> About Eclipse** and click the **Installation Details** button at the bottom left of the dialog box.
2. Select the **Force.com IDE** and click the **Uninstall...** button and follow the instructions.

**SECOND**, install previous version of Force.com IDE:

1. Go to the Eclipse menu **Help --> Install New Software...**
2. Enter "*Force.com IDE*" in the **Work With:** box and it should return **Force.com IDE - http://www.adnsandbox.com/tools/ide/install/**.  Select this option.
3. Be sure to **uncheck** the **Show only the latest versions of available software** in the bottom section of the dialog.  This should present with a full list of all versions of the API available.

***NOTE***:  You will most likely need to create a new Force.com Project once you install a previous version (ie. v.27).  I doubt the project upgrade wizard can handle the change backwards.

Comment: I am using the force.com IDE and although its built on eclipse it appears to be a bit different under Help --> i do not have "Install New Software" i have "software and workspace center" i would think that i could remove the SF.com plugging but the option is greyed out. any other suggestions?

Comment: tried a fresh install of eclipse and your instructions. this is the message when trying to install 27... " Software being installed: Force.com IDE 27.0.0.201302151147 (com.salesforce.ide.feature.feature.group 27.0.0.201302151147)
  Missing requirement: Force.com IDE 27.0.0.201302151147 (com.salesforce.ide.feature.feature.group 27.0.0.201302151147) requires 'org.eclipse.update.ui 0.0.0' but it could not be found"

Comment: You need to use Eclipse 3.7 or earlier. The Force.com IDE isn't supported on the latest version of Eclipse unfortunately.