# Why does my unpackaged Apex class have "packageVersions" XML tag and a namespace in IDE

Tags: apex, managed-package, ide, class, namespace

ZenDesk is a third party customer support tool that integrates with Salesforce.Because they had a bug with their customizations, I wrote a scheduled class that went into their custom records after they were created, and updated some information in them. I didn't make the class part of their package or anything like that AFAIK.

Recently I noticed a date-sensitive test had failed in its test class, so I downloaded the class and its test class from my production into the IDE so I could update the test and redeploy.

Here's the strange thing: when I check the xml file of those classes, they both have tags similar to managed package classes! None of my other classes have this "packageversions" tag

[image]

While all the ZenDesk file names start with ZenDesk, mine starts with "Scheduled", so I'm not sure if my filename is the cause. And when I look at the class within SF.com, it clearly doesn't have a namespace:

[image]

Can anyone explain what's going on here?

Answer (score 5):

Once any of your components reference anything from the managed package then the packageVersions tab will be populated. Its used to indicate that your class is now dependent on that package being installed.

```
<ApexClass xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>26.0</apiVersion>
    <packageVersions>
        <majorNumber>6</majorNumber>
        <minorNumber>23</minorNumber>
        <namespace>abc</namespace>
    </packageVersions>
    <status>Active</status>
</ApexClass>
```

In your case its because your scheduled class is referencing an object from the ZenDesk package.

Comment: It's important to note that this can cause intended headaches if a changeset is built in a source organization with one version installed and a destination organization with a different version installed.

Comment: Thanks guys! Followup question: When I attempt to deploy just the related test class (with a fix to improve code coverage) from the IDE, I get a validation error saying "Cannot deploy InstalledPackage in Package Manifest with any other types!". Though I'm only deploying that one, my Force project in the IDE does include other classes and triggers - is that the cause of the problem?

Comment: Have a look at http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/14020/installedpackage-failure-when-deploying-to-sandbox to see if that is any help

Comment: I had read about the issues with version 28 before, but I don't think that's it, since I've pushed other non-packaged classes successfully with my version =/

Comment: EDIT: I take it back... using the 'save to server' option instead of 'deploy to server' within the IDE worked, so I guess it's an IDE issue still. Thanks all!